# Notepad++ auto-close HTML tags in PHP files

Tags: php, html, notepad++

In Notepad++, how can I enable to auto-close HTML tags in PHP files?

I'm able to do this in HTML and XML files (I think the TextFX plugin does it), but in PHP files it doesn't work. Is there a plugin (or built-in functionality) to enable auto-close HTML tags in PHP files?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a bit annoying, but you could temporarily switch to HTML language, and when you're done, switch back to PHP language.

Answer (score 9):

Install the TextFX plugin and go to menu *TextFX* → *TextFX Settings* → +Autoclose XHTML/XML <Tag>.

Comment: pretty sure this is the answer, but you have to switch to HTML in the language menu instead of PHP :D

Answer (score 3):

Try CCompletion. It's an auto-completion plugin for Notepad++, and it might suit your needs: [here](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Plugin_Central).

Also, the next Notepad++ 5.0 will feature auto-completion. You can grab a beta version somewhere over the web - look over [here](http://www.filehippo.com/download_notepad/).

Comment: I don't think CCompletion has HTML tag auto-closing, but thanks =)

Answer (score 2):

I have found a solution which could ease up the issue.

In menu *Settings* → *Preferences* 
in the *Auto-Completion* tab, try to add `<` `>` and `?` `?`  in the blanks.

Comment: Do you mean for *"Matched pair 1"* and *"Matched pair 2"*? A screenshot (with filled-in values) would be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try [XML Tools](http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/XML%20Tools/).

Unfortunately I'm on a Mac, so I can't test, but I'm pretty sure this is the plugin I used before, and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

It's not complete, but it's convincing. You can install TextFX and go to menu *TextFX* → *TextFX Settings* → +Autoclose Brace (not HTML/XHTML).

I got it. It works.